# Job offer without visa sponsorship from employer for Ireland

Tags: working-visas, paperwork, ireland

I got a job offer from a company based out of Dublin, Ireland.

The employer told me they won't be able to sponsor visa, but they will be able to help with required documents.

I am living in India, Is it possible to get the visa with just the offer letter? without having visa sponsorship from the employer?

Update:

As per https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Labour-Market-Needs-Test/, the employer needs to advertise in multiple media sources before hiring non-EU candidate.

I don't think the employer who offered me a offer letter did that, as I see they've posted the job offer in their site just a 3 weeks ago.

Is it necessary to meet all the requirements mentioned in the "Labour market needs test"?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘visa sponsorship’? Typically, a valid offer of employment is required. Have you checked the official website http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-long-work?

Comment: @Traveller I have updated my question based on the link you've provided. It seems just the valid offer of employment won't work unless if it is advertised in said media sources.

Comment: Are you sure the offer is legitimate? It seems to me a reputable company based out of Dublin ought to be well aware of a very recently-introduced recruitment requirement. How much direct contact did you have with them before receiving the offer of employment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP hasn’t returned to confirm the validity of the job offer.

Comment: @traveller, Yes the company is legitimate. They're one of the major IT network company providing services to Irish schools and institutions, they're in business since 1990's. They have total employees of only 100, I guess. also, it seems the HR is not that much aware of visa process.

Comment: Also, I don't have any direct contact with the employer, nor referral. I have applied via their job portal.

Comment: One more point, I would like to add: I had in touch with one of the major agency today, and they told me it is not always the case that the employer needs to post the job on those job portal for those specific days.

Comment: Why is the employer unable to sponsor your visa? A waiver is available for the Needs Test in certain circumstances https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Labour-Market-Needs-Test/ Do you / the employer / job qualify for a waiver and meet all the published criteria for a work permit? https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Permit-Types/General-Employment-Permit/

Comment: @Traveller I think they're not willing to sponsor visa because of the budget issue.

Comment: @Traveller One more thing, I will be applying for critical skills work permit, in that case, I believe we don't need the Needs Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a General Employment permit you need:

- a job offer from a bona fide employer registered with the Revenue Commissioners and, if applicable, with the Companies Registration Office/Registry of Friendly Societies, and is trading in Ireland. If the employer won’t be able to sponsor your visa because they don’t meet this criteria, you can’t apply for a Permit.
- to meet the eligibility criteria (eg remuneration level, relevant skills)
- A Labour Market Needs Test, unless the job qualifies for a waiver https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Labour-Market-Needs-Test/

Source: https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Permit-Types/General-Employment-Permit/

Comment: I think they're not able to sponsor visa mostly because of budget issue than the above mentioned criteria (in point 1). I will double check with them, thanks a lot the info.

Comment: Also, can you clarify "sponsor" means sponsoring the expenses for visa application? and the flight tickets etc?

Comment: @smc If it’s the employer using the term, you should ask them exactly what they mean. Employers don’t have to pay the costs associated with a visa / relocation in order to be ‘sponsors’, it would depend on eg their recruitment and relocation policies.

Answer (score 1):

> I am living in India, Is it possible to get the visa with just the offer letter? without having visa sponsorship from the employer?

The answer is simple - No.

Work visa require the employment permit issued the govt to the Irish employer to the worker.